# Cannot deploy Cordova application because of unexpected TypeError

Tags: cordova

When I try to do a deploy of a Cordova application to a device I am getting this error. This is with Cordova 5.4.1.

```
$cordova run —debug —device android`

shell.js: internal error
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in undefined
at Object._cp (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:122:26)
at Object.cp (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/shelljs/src/common.js:186:23)
at PlatformApiPoly.prepare (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/platforms/PlatformApiPoly.js:192:15)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/prepare.js:100:32
at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:810:14
at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:458:13)
Warning: Command failed:  Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there was an issue with the code itself that was breaking the deploy. Once the code was fixed this was no longer a problem.